# Optane or SSD, is all 7th gen Intel laptop support optane?

Tags: laptop, ssd, asus-laptop, optane

First of all this is my laptop

Asus TP410UR

- Windows 10 Pro 64b
- i3 7100U
- 8GB DDR4 dual channel RAM
- GeForce 930MX
- 240GB Sata SSD

Can I use optane on my laptop?

I'm planning to upgrade my drive because my current one is already filled with game(only 3 mind you). I planned to add a 512GB m2 SSDdrive to be used as system and software drive and use my older 1TB SATA HDD as my data drive, but yesterday my office bought some laptop that have an HDD+Optane(accidentally) configuration, after I use it i feel no real different on loading and boot time with my laptop with SSD. I did some research on optane and consider optane as a good alternative for upgrading because rather than partial speed up system wide speed up is better, with that said I still have some confusion about optane.

tldr here's my question:

1. I read that aside from processor the board also need to be compatible with optane, does my laptop support it?
2. Which one is better 512GB SSD + 1TB HDD(my previous plane) or 16GB Optane + 1TB HDD? Price wise it's ~$60 for 512GB SSD and ~$20 for 16GB Optane, I won't get a 32GB Optane because the price is the same or more expensive than 512GB SSD.
3. I read that optane only can boost the primary drive, is it only in dual HDD case? Does that mean it will boost my entire 1TB drive even if I split it? I.e. if I split my drive into C and D will it boost both or will it only able to boost C?

My use case:
I use my laptop for productivity and entertainment (game, movie mostly), because it's my personal laptop I actually don't really care productivity wise but some boost is nice, my main concern is for gaming and navigating the system. I played mostly RPG(DA:I level at most) and JRPG because the spec restrain, despite the low spec for JRPG the file size is quite huge(at least the one I have).

Comment: A Optane drive can only accelerate one drive at a time.

Comment: So if I split it into C and D, it will only able to accelerate the C?